# Does "current directory" refer to where I run the command `javac`?

Tags: java

the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) says

> The default value of the class path is ".", meaning that only the current directory is searched. Specifying either the CLASSPATH variable or the -cp command line switch overrides this value.

Does "current directory" refer to where I run the command `javac`?

For example, I sign in my Windows with the account `ubuntu`, so the command prompt starts at `C:\Users\ubuntu`. And then I run the command
`C:\programs\java\jdk8\bin\javac D:\soucecode\Hello.java`. In this situation, does current directory refer to `C:\Users\ubuntu\` or `D:\soucecode\`?

Comment: `C:\Users\ubuntu\`

Comment: More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current directory is the directory where you run your command.
Since you ran your command (`javac`) in `C:\Users\ubuntu` it will be the directory.